# My network is working but browsers won't navigate to websites

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, google-chrome

I am witnessing a very strange and apparently random behaviour on a machine in my home.
This is a windows 10 machine installed when windows 10 came out and have been always automatically updated.

Since 1 month apprently at random the browsers (I tried with Chrome latest 81.0.4044.138, IE/Edge latest and Opera) stop working and won't allow navigation to websites. The network is working and connected, the ipaddress is setup and ipconfig gives a valid ip confirmed by my router.

What is even stranger is that in Google Chrome the searchbar works and gives suggestions, I can get the results from google but when I click on any links it gives ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED.
Even entering a url and trying to access it doesn't work, or even clicking on a favourite.

Apparently restarting the machine works every time ("Have you tried turning it off and on again?").
But at random it happens again.

I checked with TaskManager, Windows Events, and monitored resources for any sign of something going wrong but I can't find any strange processes that raise red flags.
This machine has installed Norton Security 360 and I tried disabling everything but apparently it's not what is causing the problem because even with everything disabled the problem still happens.

If anybody has a clue or a direction/tool that could help me to identify the problem I would be very thankful.

EDIT 19/05/2020
After installing Wireshark on that particular machine and analyzing network traffic before and after a machine restart I discovered the following:
Google Chrome searchbar was working with search hints and results because all of its traffic is routed using UDP protocol and what I discovered is that the machine STOPS completely using TCP protocol.
After a restart probably something gets reset and starts using TCP again.
I set it up to save all packets on a drive to do post crash analysis again when the problem presents itself.

Comment: Wired or wireless connection? Any events in your router's error log when it's happening?

Comment: Wired connection, I will check for the router's log. 
I add that all the other wired computers and wireless devices on the same network are behaving correctly so that pc is the only one showing a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no Logs are present on the router, they are unavailable because managed by my ISP, but on the interface the router sees the ip address of that pc correctly connected and online.

Comment: That's strange, on my router I can view the network log for my router, your ISP must have your router really locked down. Have you done any MAC address filtering on the router in the past?

Comment: No I haven't, there are no special rules set on the router per se, so it is not filtering out that particular machine or throttling the connection in some way, Anyway I am updating the question with new information.